# How do I get published as a student in Biblical Studies?

Tags: publications, research-process

I am a newcomer in research studies within Bible and Theology fields. I want to publish my own articles but do not know where to begin. How can I get my papers published formally? I am only a MA student so I am not even sure if I should start publishing yet.

Comment: Did you consider talking to your faculty advisor?

Comment: I do not have a faculty advisor only professors per each class, no advisor is given. All I am doing is research in every course and I want to go beyond that. How can it be done?

Comment: If you are doing a Masters by coursework and don't have a faculty advisor, did you try asking some of your course professors?

Comment: Doing serious research in **any** field requires finding an advisor. In addition to Darren's suggestion, consider talking to the chair of the graduate program at your department and see if they have a more specific suggestion: without knowing your department this is simply impossible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Speak with the program director or your individual professors. They should be able to advise you about what journals are ideal for your research and whether your writing is professionally sufficient for academic publication. Many people in fields like theology, philosophy, etc. learn the publishing process just by trying and by polling our professors. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks David, I should have said I did this already and the program director said my writing was ideal for publication but he said I would need to outsource and he was not willing to do that at the time. Then I went to my current professor in a class on Johannine Theology. He said I needed to find an advisor but I do not know how to go about doing that.

Comment: If I were you, I would go and review recent publications from respectable authors and journals. Then I would revise your essay as professionally as possible, following the style and structure you found in those essays. Then I would try to submitting to journals. Maybe do not start with the most important theological/Biblical journals, but begin with respected ones. The Journal of Theological Interpretation would be one example. Or you can search for journals at major publishers, like Wiley or Sage. Wipf and Stock may have decent, if smaller, journals for you to practice with also.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "outsource?"

Comment: They said "Christian you need to be careful writing. Your writing is great and well done for publication. You need to outsource your research output and input. You are a scholar in rising and taking to the stars. You have exhibited accelerated learning competencies and research ideas but you need to research your positions. You are expected to show your mastery of those pursuits as well."

Comment: Ok, that helps. I am remain less than 100% sure what the director means, but I think it means you need to network more and get more input on your ideas from the general community. Whether by doing a doctorate, going to conferences, reading more widely, networking with established scholars, etc. The last part also sounds like you need to practice the mechanics of research and widen your reading, as well. All that can be very boring, but is vastly important. Most of us only learn this by necessity in a doctorate or by experience in conference presentations.

Comment: Note, I am a PhD theology student who didn't get published until I was already about halfway through my classwork. The writing mechanics have been the hardest part for me not the theology or argument itself, so I think I get where you come from. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks David this is helpful. Can you email me? I would like to network. saucier2000.christian@gmail.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149542/discussion-between-christian-saucier-and-david-ave).

Comment: Alternatively, talk to your pastor or priest. It's possible your denomination has some sort of scholarly publishing arm you could submit your paper to.

Comment: I responded on the chat, Christian. Just fyi.

Comment: "Outsource" usually means "get a contractor to do something for you in exchange for money".  I really hope that's not what the programme director meant.